# Transition and Cypress unexpected behavior

Tags: cypress

I've tested elements with the transition. It simply changes the image after clicking and does some transition ease-out stuff. Then I've tried to use Cypress to compare if the new image is the expected URL image. But because of transition, I've got a `-webkit-cross-fade` method as an output. How to resolve that problem without using `cy.wait()`?

Code:

```
  it('test', ()=> {
        getSelectAll().click()
        cy.wait(300)
        getCheckboxes().each((elem) => {
        expect(elem).to.have.css('background-image', 
            expectedBackground)
        })
    })
```

I would like not to use `cy.wait()`.

Comment: We can help with it, but you need to share [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, do you mind telling us why you don't want to use `cy.wait()`?

Comment: Because as far as I know using cy.wait() with Number is an antipattern.

Comment: Have you tried [Timeouts](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html#Timeouts)?

Comment: Finally I've used cy.wrap on element and it works

Comment: In general, Cypress should handle most animations automatically - see [this FAQ](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#Some-of-my-elements-animate-in-how-do-I-work-around-that). Adding cy.wrap() allowed that to happen, without it you are just testing raw DOM elements.